# Difference between $_POST['v1'] and $_POST[v1] on numeric fields

Tags: php, sql, database, post

I suppose to have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE noSense(
id int,
name Varchar(25),
v1 int
);
```

If i use a post method in php, what is the difference between $_POST['v1'] and $_POST[v1] if v1 is a numeric field?

Comment: The second option generates an `E_NOTICE` error. Don't use it. (See [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).)

Answer (score 1):

`'v1'` is a string, and is a valid array key which hopefully points to a form element like `<input ... name="v1" />`.

`v1` on the other hand is likely nothing at all, and will throw an `E_NOTICE`, and also cause your code to do nothing.  However, it is possible to give `v1` a value using `define()`, but judging by your question, would be largely useless.  More likely, you are looking to use `$_POST['v1']`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` returns text strings. So if you are trying to save a post value as a number then you must convert that string to a number; you can use `intval`